# How to use HTML5 Boilerplate in a ZPT?

Tags: html5boilerplate, template-tal, zpt, template-metal

I'm trying to update one of our older ZPT based applications and I would like to implement the following HTML5 Boilerplate best practice for adding conditional IE classes to the `<html>`.

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Since I've used this technique on many non-ZPT sites I didn't think too much about it, however when I went to implement it I ran into a few problems.

1. ZPTs remove HTML comments so the rendered source lacks the conditional comments
2. We're using a whole page macro to define a reusable page template and that definition occurs in the `<html>` element like so, `<html metal:define-macro="page">`. Even once I get the conditional comments to display it seems that my next hurdle will be properly defining the page macro.

Can anyone shed some light on either of these questions?

Answer (score 0):

It's estrange, zpt doesn't remove comments. Maybe it's a particular implementation of zpt who does that? Anyways, have you tried using tal:replace="strucutre string:...."

```
<metal:macro metal:define-macro="page">
<tal:doctype tal:replace="structure string:&lt;!DOCTYPE html&quot;&gt;" />
<!-- If the comments are eaten, you can generate them using the same trick that
     tal:doctype above -->

</metal:macro>
```